# application-defined or object-defined error Ubound

Tags: vba, excel

there I have an excel VBA code that retrieves its records from an external file by month and set it according to the column heading.

However, i have an error in of application-defined or object-defined error in of the line `.Range("A6").Resize(n, 23) = b`

does anyone know why

code:

```
Sub zz()
Dim arr, c, b(), n&
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A6").AutoFilter
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\sophia.tan\Desktop\MasterPlanData.xlsx", 0, 1
arr = Sheets("Excel").UsedRange
ActiveWorkbook.Close 0
c = Array(0, 2, 13, 14, 7, 8, 11, 1, 9, 10, 16, 17, 20, 22, 15, 30, 27, 28, 29, 3, 4, 30)
d = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23)
ReDim b(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 23)

For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 12) >= DateSerial(Year:=2017, Month:=11, Day:=1) And arr(i, 12) <= DateSerial(Year:=2017, Month:=11, Day:=31) Then
        n = n + 1
        For j = 1 To UBound(c)
            b(n, d(j)) = arr(i, c(j))
        Next
    End If
Next


With Worksheets("Sheet2")

    .Range("A6:T" & Rows.Count).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>OFM"
    .Range("A6:T" & Rows.Count).CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).AutoFilter field:=13, Criteria1:="<>Collar & Cuff"
    .Range("A6:T" & Rows.Count).CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .Range("A6").Resize(n, 23) = b
    .Range("A6").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range("G6"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    .Range("A6").Select


End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = 1

End Sub
```

Comment: does *b* have a ubound(b, 2) of 23? does *b* have a ubound(b, 1) of n?

Comment: I'm not sure as I used an example code to get my code because i'm not very familiar with VBA code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your determination on **n** is subjective to the If statement. However, any unfilled values in the 'rows' of **b** will be vbnullstrings and will produce truly blank cells.

```
.Range("A6").Resize(ubound(b, 1), ubound(b, 2)) = b
```

Alternately,

```
For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 12) >= DateSerial(Year:=2017, Month:=11, Day:=1) And arr(i, 12) <= DateSerial(Year:=2017, Month:=11, Day:=31) Then
        n = n + 1
        For j = 1 To UBound(c)
            b(n, d(j)) = arr(i, c(j))
        Next
    End If
Next
b = application.transpose(b)
redim preserve b(lbound(b, 1) to ubound(b, 1), lbound(b, 2) to n)
b = application.transpose(b)
.Range("A6").Resize(n, 23) = b
```

You can only adjust the last rank of an array with ReDim when using the preserve parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.Range("A6").Resize(n, 23).Value = b
```

Comment: OK, try removing the AutoFilter before inserting the values.